# How to connect to litecoin testnet3?

Tags: litecoin, testnet, nodes

Running `litecoin-0.13.2` with `testnet=1` I get "No block source available."

Do I need to add some nodes to `litecoin.conf` ? I tried adding some that I found from http://litecointools.com/ . Is there a more official list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testnet3 is deprecated.  The development version is now on testnet4 and it appears this will be in the v0.14 release.

https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/pull/285